# Sending and receiving files keeps hanging

Tags: c#, sockets, send

my program should be able to send and receive files but for some reason whenever i click on the send (button1) and receive (button2) buttons, it keeps hanging. Not sure if its something wrong my my codes? Also, I feel like my codes are pretty long as compared to other examples i found online but I'm not sure how to rectify.

**Client codes**

```
    Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 9000);

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            socket.Connect(remoteEP);
            textBox2.Text = "Connected to Server";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            textBox2.Text = "Unable to connect to Server";
            textBox2.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }

    public const string SEND = "[SEND]";
    public const string RECEIVE = "[RECEIVE]";
    public const string QUIT = "[QUIT]";

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Clear();
        textBox2.Clear();
        NetworkStream stream = new NetworkStream(socket);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);

        try
        {
            writer.WriteLine(RECEIVE);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
            writer.Flush();
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\Y400\Desktop\Lectures\Year 3\WAD\Week 11" + textBox1.Text);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            byte[] bmpBytes = ms.GetBuffer();
            bmp.Dispose();
            ms.Close();
            int sent;
            sent = sendData(socket, bmpBytes);
            textBox1.Text = "Transferring file complete\r\n";
            textBox1.Text += bmpBytes.Length + " bytes sent to Server.";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            textBox2.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }

    public static int sendData (Socket s, byte[] data)
    {
        int total = 0;
        int size = data.Length;
        int left = size;
        int sent;

        byte[] datasize = new byte[4];
        datasize = BitConverter.GetBytes(size);
        sent = s.Send(datasize);

        while(total<size)
        {
            sent = s.Send(data, total, left, SocketFlags.None);
            total += sent;
            left -= sent;
        }
        return total;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox2.Clear();
        textBox1.Clear();
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        string fileN = textBox2.Text.Trim();
        NetworkStream ns = new NetworkStream(socket);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ns);
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(ns);
        writer.WriteLine(SEND);
        writer.Flush();
        writer.WriteLine(fileN);
        writer.Flush();
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                data = receiveData(socket);
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
                break;
            }
            textBox2.Text = ("Receiving file from server ...\r\n" + data.Length + " bytes copied");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            textBox2.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }

    public static byte[] receiveData (Socket s)
    {
        int total = 0;
        int recv;
        byte[] datasize = new byte[4];

        recv = s.Receive(datasize, 0, 4, 0);
        int size = BitConverter.ToInt32(datasize, 0);
        int dataleft = size;
        byte[] data = new byte[size];


        while (total < size)
        {
            recv = s.Receive(data, total, dataleft, 0);
            if (recv == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            total += recv;
            dataleft -= recv;
        }
        return data;
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Clear();
        textBox2.Clear();
        textBox2.Text = "Connection closed";
        socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        socket.Close();
    }
```

**Server codes**

```
    class Program
    {
    public const string SEND = "[SEND]";
    public const string RECV = "[RECV]";
    public const string QUIT = "[QUIT]";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        runServer();
    }

    static void runServer()
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            IPEndPoint localEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9000);
            server.Bind(localEP);
            server.Listen(10);

            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for Client ...");
            Socket client = server.Accept();
            Console.WriteLine("Client connected");

            NetworkStream stream = new NetworkStream(client);
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);

            try
            {
                while(true)
                {
                    string request = reader.ReadLine();
                    string filename = reader.ReadLine();
                    if (request == QUIT)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Client disconnected");
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (request == SEND)
                    {
                        getFileFromClient(filename, client);
                    }
                    else if (request == RECV)
                    {
                        receiveFileFromClient(filename, client);                        
                    }
                }
             }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public static void getFileFromClient(string filename, Socket client)
    {
        try
        {
            FileStream output = File.OpenWrite(filename);
            Console.WriteLine(filename + " created");
            int count = 0;
            while(true)
            {
                byte[] data = new byte[1024];
                int size = client.Receive(data);
                output.Write(data, 0, size);
                count += size;
                if(size<1024)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            output.Close();
            Console.WriteLine(count + " bytes read from client");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public static void receiveFileFromClient(string filename, Socket client)
    {
        int count = 0;
        FileStream input = File.OpenRead(filename);
        Console.WriteLine("Reading " + filename);
        while(true)
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead = input.Read(data, 0, 1024);
            client.Send(data, bytesRead, SocketFlags.None);
            count += bytesRead;

            if(bytesRead < 1024)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Transferring file completed\r\n" + count + " bytes sent to Client");
        input.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: So, where does it keep hanging, did you go through code with debugger?

Answer (score 1):

*Generally speaking*

...try to approach the problem differently.
You can't just copy paste stuff from the Internet and hope for the best. You need to understand what you're doing thoroughly.

*Regarding your exact problem*

Take a look at the `button2_Click` method.

It contains a `while` loop which *apparently* never finishes.

```
while (true)
{
    data = receiveData(socket);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
    break;
}
```

It does finish because of the `break` command. But this is all very hard to read.

When you copy paste code around and then apply quick fixes you end up with a pile of code which is very hard to debug.

It took me about 10 minutes to notice the fact that the client defines it's "message verbs" like so:

```
public const string SEND = "[SEND]";
public const string RECEIVE = "[RECEIVE]";
public const string QUIT = "[QUIT]";
```

while the server defines them like so:

```
public const string SEND = "[SEND]";
public const string RECV = "[RECV]";
public const string QUIT = "[QUIT]";
```

This is maybe not the only problem, but it is sufficient to create a deadlock,
because the server *never* executes the positive branch of this `if` statement:

```
else if (request == RECV)
{
    receiveFileFromClient(filename, client);                        
}
```

so the client *believes* it is about to receive something, which proves to be false.

Also make sure you send the "SEND" and "RECEIVE" message verbs when you should and not mix them up.

Good luck!

PS: I would suggest you take a look at more simpler to use techniques for sending and receiving data, such as:

- WCF
- ASP.NET Web Services
- Web API

Comment: Upvoting for finding part of the problems ;-) There are more issues!!

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring any logic errors that may occur in your programs, the way you are handling things in your client whenever it is doing an action it is doing it on the GUI thread. This will make your application seem like it is locking but instead it is executing your logic on the GUI thread.

The same problem is occurring on the server. It accepts a connection, and then goes on to receive the file. It will not be able to receive any other connection until it finished receiving the file.

The server is not without problems either because it is never checking if it receives 0 bytes from the socket. Which means that the client closed its end of the connection. You are simply assuming that if you receive less than 1024 you are receiving your last part of the file. This is simply not true for TCP. You only know you received the last part if you receive 0 bytes. TCP is a byte streaming protocol you cannot assume you will be receiving blocks of 1024 bytes. It is likely that this will be in fact the case, but you should not code it like that. Check for reception of 0 bytes. On the client you did check for 0 bytes, I am puzzled why you did not do the same on the server. The problematic part is this :

```
byte[] data = new byte[1024];
int size = client.Receive(data);
output.Write(data, 0, size);
count += size;
if(size<1024) //you can only break if the size is 0
{
     break;
}
```

There are probably more bugs. As the other answer also indicated some other issues.

Comment: Upvote :) unfortunately we're not helping, either of us. @eyeballs do you know what a byte stream is? Or more importantly what it is not? It is not a message stream, and that is an important fact. That means that while one party could send 3 "messages" to its counterpart, the later could very well receive one "big message" or 6 "littler messages". Either way, receiving "a message of length 0" means that the other party hung up. I'm talking about messages in the sense of what we humans think about that which is being sent. The weirdness of how they are received is only due to the fact that ..

Comment: @eyeballs .. they don't exist for TCP. TCP only guarantees that the compound bytes of any "send" gesture will be delivered in the exact same order to the counterpart. It doesn't state anything about when it will do so but we can all agree that it is ASAP. It doesn't state anything about borders. The last byte of this "send gesture" could be received alongside the first byte of the next "send gesture".